# I want to make a join betwen two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I have two tables one which is a variable and another is fixed.

the **$tab** structure

```
id  int(11)  autoincrement
cod     text         
den_material    text         
furnizor    varchar(255)         
cant_reper  varchar(255)         
lg  varchar(255)    No       
cod_furnizor    varchar(255)         
obs     tinytext         
data    date
```

and the **nomenclator** table structure

```
nid      int(11)    autoincrement    
sap      text            
denumire     text            
grupa    varchar(255)            
unitate
```

I want to join them to generate one single table in **$tab** with the following structure

```
id  int(11)  autoincrement
cod     text        --> to get datas from nomenclator table sap as column 
den_material    text    -> to get datas from nomenclator table denumire as column    
furnizor    varchar(255)         
cant_reper  varchar(255)         
lg  varchar(255)    No       
cod_furnizor    varchar(255)         
obs     tinytext         
data    date
```

The full source code

```
 session_start();

// preserve selection for ajax call
if (!empty($_POST["tables"]))
{
    $_SESSION["tab"] = $_POST["tables"];
    $tab = $_SESSION["tab"];
}

// update on ajax call
if (!empty($_GET["grid_id"]))
    $tab = $_SESSION["tab"];

if (!empty($tab))
{
    $g = new jqgrid();

    // set few params
    $grid["caption"] = "Comanda : '$tab'";
    $grid["autowidth"] = true;
    $grid["multiselect"] = false; // allow you to multi-select through checkboxes
$grid["form"]["position"] = "center";
$grid["view_options"] = array("width"=>"500");



    $g->select_command = "SELECT t.* FROM `$tab` AS t, `nomenclator` AS n
WHERE n.`sap` = t.`cod` OR n.`denumire` = t.`den_material`;";



    $g->set_options($grid);

    $g->set_actions(array(  
                        "add"=>true, // allow/disallow add
                        "edit"=>true, // allow/disallow edit
                        "delete"=>true, // allow/disallow delete
                        "view"=>true, // allow/disallow delete
                        "rowactions"=>true, // show/hide row wise edit/del/save option
                        "search" => "advance", // show single/multi field search condition (e.g. simple or advance)
                        "showhidecolumns" => false
                    ) 
                );




    // set database table for CRUD operations

    $g->table = $tab;


    $col = array();
$col["title"] = "sap";
$col["name"] = "sap"; 
$col["width"] = "10";
$col["editable"] = true;
$col["hidden"] = true;
$cols[] = $col;  



$col = array(); 
    $col["index"] = "furnizor";
    $col["title"] = "Comerciale asigurate de: ";
    $col["editable"] = true;
    $col["edittype"] = "select"; // render as checkbo
$col["editoptions"] = array("value"=>'Ramira:Ramira;Beneficiar:Beneficiar', "multiple" => true);
    $cols[] = $col;

        $col = array();
$col["index"] = "den_material";
$col["title"] = "Denumire Material";
$col["name"] = "denumire"; 
$col["editable"] = true;
$col["width"] = "80";
$col["searchoptions"] = array("value" => $str, "separator" => ":", "delimiter" => ";");
$col["search"] = true;
$col["formatter"] = "autocomplete"; // autocomplete
$col["formatoptions"] = array(  "sql"=>"SELECT t.* 
FROM `$tab` AS t, `nomenclator` AS n
WHERE n.`sap` = t.`cod` OR n.`denumire` = t.`den_material`;",
                                "search_on"=>"name", 
                                "update_field" => "sap");
$cols[] = $col;
```

Comment: you mean to say you want to join a php variable to a table in the database?

Comment: You say "that would help [you] get a raise" so I will recommend you to learn the job that people pay you to do.

Comment: What @MaoTseTongue said. What you're doing is basically stealing money by getting paid for things you have no clue about. Learn the technology, don't beg for code snippets. If you can't learn it, find a job that suits your skills.

Comment: Voting to close because this is a "write my code for me" question. It's also a duplicate of any number of "how do I make a join" questions.

Comment: i am not a programmer i work in logistics and our IT doesen't know programming i tried several times to do it but i couldn't that's why i asked for help.

Comment: Come on, @NB, let's not pile it on. He gets points for honesty.

Comment: @Radu, still the answer to your question is "look for a tutorial on the JOIN operation in SQL." Or (my recommendation) show your best work so far, and ask for help. Just posting the problem makes you no friends on stackoverflow.

Comment: i tried to help the company with that php script but i have that problem, i am a newbie in programming and the person from the it besides the fact that is a noob is proud of it. And he didn't care to help the others, maybe i get the raise maybe no my current salary is at about 150$ per month.

Comment: I tried but didn't worked and that's why i posted here hoping for help...

Comment: Do you have any foreign key in your tables?

Comment: anyone that can figure the question out deserves a raise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query will get rows, which have both data in $tab as same as in nomenclator.

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM `$tab` AS t, `nomenclator` AS n
WHERE n.`sap` = t.`cod` AND n.`denumire` = t.`den_material`;
```

---

Below query will get rows, which have any data in $tab as same as in nomenclator.

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM `$tab` AS t, `nomenclator` AS n
WHERE n.`sap` = t.`cod` OR n.`denumire` = t.`den_material`;
```

---

Try above queries. If you don't get desired result set, reply here

Comment: Couldn't execute query. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0' at line 1 - SELECT t.* FROM `test123` AS t, `nomenclator` AS n WHERE n.`sap` = t.`cod` OR n.`denumire` = t.`den_material`; LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0

Comment: i posted here is the full source code

Comment: you should remove ';' after `t.den_material`

Comment: thanks but i have an issue with autocomplete send me an email on radusacalaseni [at] gmail [dot] com to send you the complete source code.